# Dynamically generated class and variable name

Tags: python, pandas

I have csv like this,

```
name,job
Jay,engineer
Kay,layer
hop,warrior
```

then I load this in `pandas` `datafrme` and put in DB

```
df = pd.read_csv('job.csv')

for index,row in df.iterrows():
   q = Issue(name = row[0],job = row[1])
   q.save()
   print ("Register : ",row[0] , " / ",row[1])
exit()
```

It works well but now, I want to generalize this code as function like this below.

```
def stor_db(classname):
    df = pd.read_csv(classname + '.csv')

    for index,row in df.iterrows():
       q = `classname`(
           `title[0]ofdf` = row[0],
           `title[1]ofdf` = row[1])
       q.save()
       print ("Register : ",row[0] , " / ",row[1])
    exit()
```

I need to dynamically make variable/class name.

It possible for python and pandas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in Python is an object, including classes.

The builtin type() is mostly used to check a variable type but there is a least known usage.
If type() is used with 3 parameters, it creates a new type Object.

The first parameter is the name of your class,
the second is the tuple of bases classes for inheritance,
the third is a dict that will becomes the __dict__ attribute.

```
Example = type("Example", (object,), {"a" : 0})

# equivalent to

class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 0
```

So you can do something like that

```
   Example = type(classname, (object,), {title[0]ofdf = row[0], title[1]ofdf = row[1]})
```

Inherit a base class with the needed methods instead of object and you'll have the common methods you need.

EDIT:

If your classes are Django models it completely changes the nature of the problem and this solution is not pertinent. Your models already exists so you don't really want to **create** classes dynamically, but **pick** the model dynamically.

I think I'll go with a load_from_csv method using __class__.__name_, shared via inheritance and use kwargs as parameters to the constructors (assuming the models attributes exactly match the csv columns).

Comment: Thank you very much, it is quite useful to understand. So now What I want to make is django model declared in model.py `object,class Issue(models.Model):` ,So now I tried to do like this , `q = type("Issue",(models.Model,),{'name' : 'testname','job' : 'test'})` but it shows  error  `module = attrs.pop('__module__')
KeyError: '__module__' `

Comment: Well I think going towards this way is not adapted then, see my edit.

Comment: I see.. but thanks to your answer It gave me new knowledge about python. I need to understand django framework more

Answer (score 1):

You can create classes dynamically with [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type). Check [this tutorial](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_classes_and_type.php) for code examples. For dynamic adding attributes, you can use [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) providing the variable name as a string.